# Need a data structure for storing data in java

Tags: java

I am working in java. I need built in `data structure` if exit. Below `data` is just example in my mind. For example: If I have this data.

```
data = [('A' , 'valueA0'),('A' , 'valueA1'),
                ('B' , 'valueB0'),('B' , 'valueB1'),
                ('C' , 'valueC0'),('C' , 'valueC1'),
                      ]
```

For accessing it just like `data["B"][0]`. It should return `valueB0` and for `data["B"][1]`. It should return `valueB1`

Is there any `data structure` exits in `java` that fullfill my needs?

Comment: you heard about a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) yet?

Comment: java doesn't provide mechanisms to operator overloading, `["B"]` needs to be replaced by map's `.get("B")`

Comment: @KevinEsche I worked on it but what if I find to value `5` of `BMW`? from this code `Map vehicles = new HashMap();
              vehicles.put("BMW", 5);
              vehicles.put("BMW", 7);
              vehicles.put("Mercedes", 3);
              vehicles.put("Audi", 4);
              vehicles.put("Ford", 10);
                
              System.out.println(vehicles.get("BMW"));`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I want to find the custom value of `B`. It can be first or second or third. How find first value of `B`?

Comment: @Humty first of, use the generics as `Map<String, Integer>`. Secondly, you know you can encapsulate the `Map` aswell like `Map<String<Map<Integer, Integer>>`?

Comment: @Humty, `Map<String, int[]>`

Comment: see this in python. It can be done in python. `Material = [
                ('BaseLinksData' , 'div'),('BaseLinksData' , 'content'),
                ('MainContent', 'p'),
                ('Comment', 'div'),('Comment' , 'comment-entry'),
                     ] 
#       
    dictionary = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in Material:
        dictionary[k].append(v)

    print(dictionary['BaseLinkData'][0])`

Comment: @KevinEsche, `int[]` is a reference type which contains primitives, therefore we can use it as a generic type

Comment: @Humty see this is java, and it can´t be done like that here.

Comment: @KevinEsche, but using `List<Integer>` as a value is a better choice as for me

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if he just wants a consecutive index for the second "index", yeah totally. But he wants to skip values and use the index more ore less like a key, therer is no way he could avoid another `Map`.

Comment: @KevinEsche .. Andrew Tobilko See the down answer suggested by Micheal But is not wastage of memory by using multiple arrays?

Comment: @Humty no, these are the stanard collections if you want something like dynamic arrays. Aswell as your basic idea would also be just an array of arrays, so i don´t see the difference, just that the given answer doesn´t have a fixed size and can use different keys for the map, and not just an `int`.

Comment: @KevinEsche Thanks dear. Ok then I am accepting his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Also, if I understand your question correctly, this is what you're trying to do in Java :

**Structure :**

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

**How to initialize it :**

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("valueA0");
a.add("valueA1");

List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("valueB0");
a.add("valueB1");

List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("valueC0");
a.add("valueC1");

map.put("A", a);
map.put("B", b);
map.put("C", c);
```

**How to use it :**

```
String a0 = map.get("A").get(0);
```

Comment: B . But your suggestion has multiple arrays. It is a simply wastage of memory.

Comment: I can't be "waste of memory" since that is what you're asking... Unless I didn't understand you're question correctly